# Firefox rendering: same version, same os, different results

Tags: firefox, layout, render

I'm testing a site and I'm getting different results using the same Firefox version on the same OS.

This [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13663835/firefox.png) is displaying some of those issues on the orange button. It shows the results of the same page on fresh installs of Firefox on Windows 7 at the same time (the top one is running on the Windows Virtual PC).

Is it possible that the rendering engine has different settings? Do you know why this happens? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, graphics hardware acceleration is not available in the virtual machine.  That makes Firefox use GDI instead of DirectWrite for the text rendering, which means no subpixel positioning of text and slightly different font metrics.  So if the button size depends on the rendered size of the text, the button will come out a different size.

You should be able to check on the graphics acceleration state in `about:support`.

Comment: Wow man, looks like you're write! The VM does have the DirectWrite disabled. I also noticed that those dimensions issues were related to custom fonts. Do you think there's a way to check if Firefox have DirectWrite enabled with JS or CSS?

Comment: Not easily.  You could try measuring some pieces of text using `getBoundingClientRect()` and seeing if their widths come out as non-integers.  I _think_ that can't happen with GDI, though I'm not sure, but should happen pretty often with DirectWrite.

Comment: Thanks again Boris, I'll give a try.

Comment: Good luck.  But one more note: on non-Windows operating systems, you will also get subpixel rendering.  Going back several years now on MacOS and Linux.  Note only that, but the font metrics for the same font can be different from either DirectWrite or GDI there.  So it's really best to not rely on specific font metrics...

Answer (score 0):

My experience with virtual machines is that the virtual display is typically smaller than the physical display.  Naturally there's a window frame, etc., when the virtual display is not in full screen mode, so naturally the virtual display tends to be smaller just to fit on the physical display.  I'm not familiar with why this might be, but I believe I've sometimes seen a slight difference in size, even when in "full screen mode", which is the mode which appears to be in use in your screenshot.

So I'm a bit surprised if the button is actually wider on the virtual display.  Is there any chance that the labels, "Windows 7" versus "Windows 7 (Windows Virtual PC)", could be reversed on the screen shot?  Or alternatively, that the 251 versus 256 pixel labels are reversed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The labels are correct and I got the same result as the Virtual on the Adobe Browser Lab.